# RecyclerView is messed up when scrolling

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

As you can see in the screenshot, my project contains a `RecyclerView` (for categories of food) which contains more `RecyclerView`s (for the ingredients). But iv'e got a problem, my `RecyclerView` is messing up the order. I debuged the project and the parameters are just fine but the `RecyclerView` is displaying them wrong. As you can see in the picture, Fruits ingredients are displayed in the Dairy category.

[image: image which display the problem of the RecyclerView messed up]

**IngredientSectionAdapter.Java**
(the main adapter,which contain more `RecyclerView`s)

```
class SectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView sectionBtn;
    private RecyclerView itemRecyclerView;

    public SectionViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        sectionBtn = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_category);
        itemRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ingredientsRecycler);
    }
}

private Context context;
private ArrayList<IngredientSectionModel> sectionModelArrayList;
ArrayList<IngredientItemAdapter> adapters;

public IngredientSectionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<IngredientSectionModel> sectionModelArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.sectionModelArrayList = sectionModelArrayList;
    adapters = new ArrayList<IngredientItemAdapter>();
}

@Override
public SectionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_list,null);
    return new SectionViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SectionViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final IngredientSectionModel sectionModel = sectionModelArrayList.get(position);
    holder.itemRecyclerView.setTag(holder.itemRecyclerView.getVisibility());
    final RecyclerView sectionList = holder.itemRecyclerView;
    holder.sectionBtn.setText(sectionModel.getSectionLabel());

    //recycler view for items
    holder.itemRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    holder.itemRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    /* set layout manager on basis of recyclerview enum type */

    StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3,1);
    adapters.add(new IngredientItemAdapter(context, sectionModel.getItemArrayList()));
    int resId = R.anim.grid_layout_animation_from_bottom;
    //LayoutAnimationController animation = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, resId);
    holder.itemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    holder.itemRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapters.get(position));
    //holder.itemRecyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(animation);

    //toggle visibilty of inner RecyclerView (ingredients, not categories)
    holder.sectionBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (sectionList.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                sectionList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                sectionList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**What can cause this?**

Comment: Is the problem present when the list first shows up, or when you scroll to bottom and back?

Comment: try using `getItemId()` and `getItemViewType()`. these function fix many problems about orders and positions in **RecyclerView**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time `onBindViewHolder` is called you create a new `IngredientItemAdapter` and add it to your `adapters`, and then you call `holder.itemRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapters.get(position))`. However, `adapters.get(position)` is not the adapter you just created. Your adapter will get bigger and bigger. Try this

```
IngredientItemAdapter adapter = adapters.get(position);
adapter.setIngredients(sectionModel.getItemArrayList());
holder.itemRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```